# Compare Twitter Hashtag Volume using twitteR package

Tags: r, twitter, scrape

I would like to use the twitteR package in R to compare the number (count) of mentions of two competing hashtags from 11/14/2012-11/22/2012 (i.e. an 8-day time period). For example, I would like hourly comparisons of two hashtags: #A vs #B.

I am wondering if there is a way to use the twitteR package in R to do this. Something using the searchTwitter function:

```
searchTwitter(searchString, n=25, lang=NULL, since=NULL, until=NULL,
              locale=NULL, geocode=NULL, sinceID=NULL, ...)
```

I am not interested in grabbing all tweets, just getting an hourly count comparison for #A vs. #B over the specified time period. I know I have to be cognizant of the rate limit and maybe will have to do some clever sampling of tweets to avoid the rate limit. Any ideas if this is feasible, and how I would go about coding it?

Answer (score 1):

I would pull 100 tweets for each hash tag every 2 minutes. Use #TweetsReturned / (TimePulled - TimeOfOldestTweet) to get a Tweets per Unit Time estimate. You can plot these to get a moving average type chart of activity over time. If you do tweets per 2 minutes, just add them up to estimate tweets per hour.